# Out of Memory Exception when trying to execute test for Apache Jena via MockMVC and Junit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit5, jena, mockmvc

I am running an Apache Jena Fuseki server als the SPARQL endpoint that I can connect to when using the application normally. Everything works and I get the output from the resulting query.

But When I try to run my test with Springboot, Junit5 (I assume) and MockMVC it always get stuck on the following part:

```java
ResultSet setNew = exec.execSelect();
```

The test then hangs until I get an out of memory exception, setting it to 12G with -Xmx also doesn't fix the issue. There is some underlying thing that I just don't understand. Has everyone ever experienced this? Am I doing something wrong? Is it even this code that is faulty?

Feel free to comment if I need to post more code. I change a lot of things to try to make it work, but to no avail. I also had to un-comment the Jacoco test suite from gradle, because it also hangs on Jacoco tests. So I think it has something to do with an infinite loop, but I don't see it.

I did start to use streams for the first time in my life, maybe that is the issue? (Mostly in code that I haven't posted here).

Code snippets:

Sparql Query

```sql
SELECT  ?object1 ?predicate2 ?object2
WHERE
  { ?id1  ?predicate1  ?object1
    FILTER ( regex(str(?predicate1), "Amsterdam", "i") || regex(str(?object1), "Amsterdam", "i") )
    ?id2  ?predicate2  ?object2
    FILTER ( regex(str(?predicate2), "city", "i") || regex(str(?object2), "city", "i") )
  }
```

Query Code

```java
public ResultSet query(Query query, String endpoint) {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    log.info(String.format("Query being executed: %s on %s", query.toString(), endpoint));
    try (QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(endpoint, query)) {
        //((QueryEngineHTTP) exec).addParam("timeout", "30000");
        ResultSet setNew = exec.execSelect();

        resultSet = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(setNew);
        log.info("Query has been executed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

My Test

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class FactCheckControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void testCheckFactSuccess() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/factcheck")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content("{\"text\": \"Amsterdam is a city.\"}"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
//                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.triplets[0].subject").value("Amsterdam"))
//                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.triplets[0].predicate").value("is"))
//                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.triplets[0].object").value("small"));
    }
}
```

Error log with --stacktrace option enabled (gradle worker)

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> Process 'Gradle Test Executor 1' finished with non-zero exit value 1
  This problem might be caused by incorrect test process configuration.
  Please refer to the test execution section in the User Manual at https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.3/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:test_execution
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 43s
```

Logging when running the normal application:

```
2021-05-11 13:10:57.425  INFO 2396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.factcheck.data.JenaRDFConnector      : Query has been executed
2021-05-11 13:10:57.425  INFO 2396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.factcheck.domain.FactDeterminer      : Setting ResultSet!
2021-05-11 13:10:57.425  INFO 2396 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.s.factcheck.domain.FactDeterminer      : Checking Fact!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| object1     | predicate2                                        | object2                             |
=========================================================================================================
| "Amsterdam" | <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> | <https://dbpedia.org/ontology/City> |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Edit: Added turtle file which contains the used data in Fuseki.

```
@prefix schema: <http://schema.org/> .
@prefix pq:    <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/> .
@prefix bd:    <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> .
@prefix pr:    <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/> .
@prefix ps:    <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix wdt:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> .
@prefix wds:   <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/statement/> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix wdv:   <http://www.wikidata.org/value/> .
@prefix skos:  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix psn:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/value-normalized/> .
@prefix pqn:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/value-normalized/> .
@prefix wd:    <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> .
@prefix geo:   <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> .
@prefix psv:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/value/> .
@prefix dct:   <http://purl.org/dc/terms/> .
@prefix pqv:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/qualifier/value/> .
@prefix ontolex: <http://www.w3.org/ns/lemon/ontolex#> .
@prefix wdata: <http://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityData/> .
@prefix wdref: <http://www.wikidata.org/reference/> .
@prefix prov:  <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#> .
@prefix cc:    <http://creativecommons.org/ns#> .
@prefix wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> .
@prefix prn:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/value-normalized/> .
@prefix dbo:   <https://dbpedia.org/ontology/> .
@prefix wdtn:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct-normalized/> .
@prefix p:     <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/> .
@prefix rdf:   <https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dbr:   <https://dbpedia.org/resource/> .
@prefix prv:   <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/reference/value/> .
@prefix hint:  <http://www.bigdata.com/queryHints#> .
@prefix wdno:  <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/novalue/> .

<http://www.dataset.org/turtle/Amsterdam>
        a             dbo:City ;
        rdfs:label    "Amsterdam" ;
        dbo:areaCode  "020" ;
        dbo:country   dbr:Netherlands .

<http://www.dataset.org/turtle/ArnoldSchwarzenegger>
        a           wdata:Q5 ;
        rdfs:label  "Arnold Schwarzenegger" .
```

Comment: In the mocking is the query going ot the same data? `ResultSetFactory.copyResults` is client side and will have all the results in memory. If it is just one row, not important. But the query on large or different data has the potential to be a huge number of results. What does the server log say?

Comment: I have added the turtle file (Which I hand crafted) to made sure that everything worked. But with only two nodes it's couldn't really go wrong right?

Comment: Your query looks odd, there's no shared variables between the two triple patterns (and filters) so you're calculating a cross product i.e. you are effectively exploding the query search space (effectively N x N where N is the size of your dataset).You might want to think more about what your query is trying to achieve and consider refactoring it.

Comment: With 6 triples, the cross product is 36 rows to filter (at worst) which si trivia. Something else is going on; it's not the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found was that the heap size was constantly overflowing. Adding the line:

```
maxHeapSize '2g'
```

To the test area in my build.gradle solved the problem (I still don't have any idea as of why that is though).

Complete build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'info.solidsoft.pitest' version '1.6.0'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.1.1"
}

group = 'com.nlxdodge.factcheck'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Spring Boot Web
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.4.5'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.4.5'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.4.5'

    // Lombok Annotation Processor
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.20'

    // Stanford NLP
    implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:4.2.0'
    implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:4.2.0:models'
    implementation 'edu.stanford.nlp:stanford-corenlp:4.2.0:models-english'

    // Jena
    implementation 'org.apache.jena:apache-jena-libs:4.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.jena:jena-querybuilder:4.0.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    maxHeapSize '2g'
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    finalizedBy 'pitest'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        afterEvaluate {
            classDirectories.setFrom(files(classDirectories.files.collect {
                fileTree(dir: it, exclude: [
                        'com/nlxdodge/factcheck/service/config/**',
                        'com/nlxdodge/factcheck/FactCheckApplication**'
                ])
            }))
        }
    }
}

pitest {
    junit5PluginVersion = '0.12'
    targetClasses = ['com.nlxdodge.factcheck.*']
    outputFormats = ['XML', 'HTML']
    timestampedReports = false
}

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property 'sonar.exclusions',
                [
                        "**/com/nlxdodge/factcheck/FactCheckApplication**"
                ]
    }
}
```